# How to query models with a related model in a onetoone relationship in Django?

Tags: django, django-queryset

Models from [the one-to-one Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/db/examples/one_to_one/):

```py
from django.db import models


class Place(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=80)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.name} the place"


class Restaurant(models.Model):
    place = models.OneToOneField(
        Place,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        primary_key=True,
    )
    serves_hot_dogs = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    serves_pizza = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

How would I query "Place objects with name 'foo' or Place objects that have a Restaurant"?

It needs to be one queryset, so I can return it to django-ninja for an API.

Answer (score 0):

After reading and experimentation, I think the answer is

```
from django.db.models import Q

qs = Place.objects.filter(Q(name="foo") | Q(restaurant__isnull=False))
```